# Active Directory - search by specifying a search filter and search controls and no context

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I followed [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JNDI-LDAP/howtoperformasearchbyspecifyingasearchfilterandsearchcontrolstosearchasubtree.htm) tutorial to search in active directory.

Sample code :

```
class SearchSubtree {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>(11);
    env
        .put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389/o=JNDITutorial");

    try {
      DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

      String[] attrIDs = { "sn", "telephonenumber", "golfhandicap", "mail" };
      SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
      ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
      ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

      String filter = "(&(sn=Geisel)(mail=*))";

      NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("", filter, ctls);

      // Print the answer
      ctx.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

But `NameNotFoundException` is thrown at

`NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("", filter, ctls);`

But when I pass, `"DC=extldap,DC=com"` as first argument, code works fine.

Is there any issue with the tutorial? Can first argument not be empty string? Or is this a limitation with Active Directory?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, for LDAP servers you always need a root context to start your search from. Basically, you are doing the equivalent of trying to search a SQL database without specifying a database or table name.

Some server implementations may allow an empty context (I know iPlanet used to allow it in some cases) but these are exceptions to the rule.

The javadoc for `DirContext.search()` says:

> Searches in the named context or object for entries that satisfy the
>   given search filter. Performs the search as specified by the search
>   controls.
>
> See `search(Name, String, SearchControls)` for details.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - name the name of the context or object to search
>
> ...

Usually, in Active Directory it is fine to start searching from the domain root, which is always `DC=<your>,DC=<domain>`. 
That is why your second search works.

Comment: But this works for OpenDJ. Is there some difference between OpenDJ and AD?

Comment: OpenDJ is a descendant of iPlanet afaik. That implementation did allow an empty root. Come to think of it, eDirectory also allows that. Maybe AD is more of an exception than I thought.